# Is there a way to force generated soldiers to always be drawn from my character pool?

Tags: xcom-2

So the character pool feature in XCOM 2 is really cool, since it lets you store a bunch of soldiers which will then be used to populate the random recruits you see. The only thing I'm wondering, though, is if there's a way to ensure that when a the list of initial and recruitable  soldiers is made that those pool soldiers will always be chosen in place of the random recruits (provided there are any available).

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers were correct but now there is an in game setting for this on the character pool screen. This was added in the March 10, 2016 patch.

Answer (score 11):

> This is no longer required, since they added options to the character pool menu in the latest patch. [See here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/261715/8350).

Yup, it's possible, and really easy to do too.

Open up `\path\to\steam\SteamApps\common\XCOM 2\XComGame\Config\DefaultXCOMGameData.ini`, and then find the following lines:

```
InitialSoldiersCharacterPoolSelectionMode=eCPSM_Mixed
RewardUnitCharacterPoolSelectionMode=eCPSM_Mixed
...
RecruitsCharacterPoolSelectionMode=eCPSM_Mixed
```

Update these values to the following:

```
InitialSoldiersCharacterPoolSelectionMode=eCPSM_PoolOnly
RewardUnitCharacterPoolSelectionMode=eCPSM_PoolOnly
...
RecruitsCharacterPoolSelectionMode=eCPSM_PoolOnly
```

Changing all of these values to **CPSM_PoolOnly** will ensure characters will always be drawn from your character pool if available, but will revert back to random generation if there's no unused soldiers in the character pool ([source](https://twitter.com/M_Nauta/status/693937952745852928)).

Answer (score 2):

This is now a Steam workshop mod for this:  [Character Pool Only](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=617408633)